# How to prevent to write characters like into a string?

Tags: java, xml, string, character-encoding

I have a problem with extracting text from scientific articles.
I use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to extract text from pdf. The
problem is not from extraction process but with some special math notations that leads to problem when I want to write the extracted text into an XML file, the special character which is not extracted correctly will cause trouble. Instead of , `&#2;` or other similar HTML codes will be inserted to the XML file and ruins the whole file. How to fix this issue?

The HTML codes that I mean are look like [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hxt0028(v=vs.80).aspx) and at the moment, number 218 is the trouble. But I guess for different math notations, different HTML codes will be replaced and cause the problem afterward.

I have already tried following string cleanings but didn't help:

```
nextWord=nextWord.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]", "");
nextWord=nextWord.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
nextWord=nextWord.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a pre-check before writing each line to a file, to check whether the text does not contain ambiguous characters. Below pattern contains all basic characters in any given textbook. You may add or remove as per your content.

```
public boolean isValidCharacters(String word){
    String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*()_+={}|\\,.?: -]*$";
    return word.matches(pattern);
}
```

Comment: your second line gives "illegal escape character" exception.

Comment: you should fix the exception first

Comment: Missed your comment.
Updated the pattern - Please try now,

Comment: I found the problem, it should be \\ not \

Comment: No, it was because of missing double quotes at start. Edited, try now.

Comment: not really, it was for single slash. :D but it is working now at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something yourself with a regex or if you have other String manipulations to do the Apache StringUtils are really great. It has a isAlpha() isNumeric() method that is easy to implement.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html